# How to correctly install data files with setup.py?

Tags: python, import

Using python 3.8 I have the following structure in a test library:

```
testrepo
    setup.py
    Manifest.in
    util/
        mycode.py
        data/
            mydata.txt
```

The file `setup.py` looks like

```
setup(
    name='testrepo',
    version="0.1.0",
    packages=['util'],
    author='Tester',
    description='Testing repo',
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data={
        "util.data": ["*"]
    },
)
```

and using the following `Manifest.in`:

```
include util/data/mycode.txt
```

and when I install this package I do not see any hint of the `data` folder in `venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/util` (when installing the repo into a python virtual environment).

How to do it correctly, so I can read the content from the file `util/data/mydata.txt` using

```
from util import data
import importlib.resources as import_resources
text = import_resources.read_text(data, "mydata.txt")
```

or whatever...

Where can I find this completely documented, with examples etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you have to do is to create the following basic structure of the repo:

```
myrepo
    setup.py
    Manifest.in
    mypackage/
        __init__.py
        mycode.py
        data/
            __init__.py
            mydata.txt
```

Just make sure to keep in mind 6 additional steps:

1. You need to put the data folder inside your package folder
2. You need to add `__init__.py` inside your data folder.
3. In `setup.py` you **have** to use `packages=find_packages(),` to find your packages.
4. In `setup.py`, you have to set `include_package_data=True,`
5. In `setup.py`, you have to specify the path to your data files:

   ```
    package_data={
        "mypackage.data": ["*"]
    },
   ```
6. You also have to define a **second** file names `Manifest.in` containing again your data files as follows (using a placeholder here - you can also add each file in a separate line):

   ```
    include util/data/*
   ```

It you are lucky, then you can include/use your data file like

```
from mypackage import data
import importlib.resources as import_resources
text = import_resources.read_text(data, "mydata.txt")
```

or

```
with import_resources.path(data, "mydata.txt") as filename:
    myfilename = filename
```

to get the path to the data file.

Not sure this is documented anywhere.